# Matching ReadEndElement with ReadStartElement when using an XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

My question is simple.  I've been using `ReadStartElement` and `ReadEndElement` with the `XmlReader` in my code just fine.  The question is (and this is after looking at MSDN), do you need to match the two?

In other words, do I end with `ReadEndElement` for each and every `ReadStartElement` or is are there cases where you don't need so many `ReadEndElement` calls in your code when reading an XML Envelop?  Thee have been cases where I did not always have a matching `ReadEndElement` and reading the xml worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe you do need to match them most often. This is because both the `ReadStartElement` and `ReadEndElement` move the XmlReader to the next node. However, they check for different things.

This unnecessarily added verbosity in the code is just one reason I always prefer to navigate XML using an `XPathNavigator`. It's convenience is simply unmatched (unless you compare it with LINQ.)

Comment: +1 agree with all - on a side note I just learned on another question/answer you can use xpath with linq2sql: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea to not put then in the code. You can get into trouble with certain xml element hierachies depending on which one you miss. Maybe only the last elements.

That said, I use linq 2 xml instead, so I don't have to deal with this :) You can load a reader on XElement.Load, and work with it in a cleaner way.